# xampp mysql: select command denied

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am using xampp om windows 7. I logged in as the root user with the password i have set up. I created a new database(I am using xampp for the first time). and I am not getting any option for creating any tables in it.
It shows the following error:

```
Error
SQL query: DocumentationEdit

SELECT `tables` 
FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma_recent`
WHERE `username` =  'root'

MySQL said: Documentation

#1142 - SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'pma_recent'
```

How do I get rid of this?

I get this line also, somewhere at the bottom of the page along with the error message:

```
The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated.
```

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

```
GRANT SELECT ON db.table TO 'user'@'localhost';

GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost'; ------------ i think this is much better.
```